# Silverstripe where to set redirect when user gets logged out because of inactivity from frontend

Tags: silverstripe

Every time a user is 15min inactive silverstripe will log out users from the front-end and redirects them to the registration page.

I have not set any of this manualy and i have no glue where this is coming from. So I guess this is implemented by silverstripe itself?

I realy tried hard to find a solution. So maybe some one can help me or point me in the right direction. Where can I change the redirect after logout. This is how i would do it:

```
    $this->redirect('security/login')
```

Thats all. But i was not able to find out where to put it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean, but as you can see on [`Member::logOut()`](http://api.silverstripe.org/en/3.6/source-class-Member.html#672-696) there are some extension hooks you can make use of, a member extension like below could be what you're looking for:

```
class MyMemberExtension extends DataExtension
{
    public function memberLoggedOut()
    {
        Controller::curr()->redirect('/MyDesiredPage');
    }
}
```

Now, by default Silverstripe won't log people out due to inactivity so that seems like the work of some custom code that has been put in place on your website either by a module or another dev.

Comment: Cheers i'll give it a try.